# Google Play Game Services Snapshot bitmap size

Tags: android, bitmap, google-play-services

I have created a game for Android that uses the Google Play game Services. One of things I use from that are the Save Games or Snapshot functionality.

To create a new snapshot I use the code below.

```
SnapshotMetadataChange metadataChange = new SnapshotMetadataChange.Builder()
                .setDescription(description)
                .setProgressValue(saveGame.getProgressInLevel())
                .setCoverImage(saveGame.coverImage)
                .build();
        Games.Snapshots.commitAndClose(gameHelper.getApiClient(), saveGameResult.snapshot, metadataChange);
```

One of the thinks I save in the snapshot is a cover image.

Now I'm seeing some problem reports with OutOfMemoryError's. Most likely this is causing by a cover image that is to big. So, my question here is: What are the requirements of that bitmap? How big can it be? What resolution can it have? And what aspect ration is the best?

I was unable to find any answers on this in the documentation from Google.

Answer (score 0):

"Google Play games services currently enforce size limits on binary data and cover image sizes of 3 MB and 800 KB respectively."

This information can be found in this [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames).

I think your cover image size is more than 800 KB. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have been thinking about your anwser and I think the bitmaps I put in there are much bigger. Let's say my app is putting in a image that is 800x800 pixels. That's 640.000 pixels. Encoded with ARGB, that would make 2.560.000 bytes. That is 2,5 MB. And I never had any complants on that. So I asume the Google Play Services library is downscaling that?